# Fast string comparison in C

Tags: c, string, compare

I currently have this kind of loop

```
while(1)
{
    generate_string(&buffer);

    for(int i = 0; i < filelines; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(buffer,line[i]) == 0)
        {
           /*  do something  */
        }
    }
}
```

I have a file with a few million strings(which hopefully should be cut by half sometime soon), the number of all these strings is stored in **filelines**

line[i] is basically where the string itself is stored.

Currently, due to the comparison of these million strings, function **generate_string(&buffer);** is executed around 42 times per second.
Is there a faster way to do string comparison in C?

Comment: @KingsIndian: no, because the real question here isn't "how to compare two strings", it's "how to test a string for containment in a large collection of strings".

Comment: Only if the string´s sizes are equal, you could do a if((buffer[0] == line[0]) && (buffer[1] == line[1]) && ...). That is faster than call strcmp().

Comment: I just ran a profile on wakkerbot: it uses 200ms to do 2M lookups in a 500K dictionary of known words. Including a final strcmp() at the matching hashtable entry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`strcmp` is usually optimized by all vendors. However, if you're not satisfied with this you can try:

- Lookup [Burst Tries](https://web.archive.org/web/20140604012229/http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/%7Ejz/fulltext/acmtois02.pdf)
- Use a suffix tree for fast string comparison -- see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20220518171317/http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/mobasher/classes/csc575/Suffix_Trees/index.html) article
- Depending on the size of strings in your application you can write a custom string comparator. E.g: GNU `libc` used to have this optimization for small strings where they tested strings smaller than five bytes as integers. MS `cl` also has some optimizations for small-strings (do look it up).

But more importantly make sure `strcmp` is your ***real*** bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, strcmp is the bottleneck. Removing the strcmp call, the function is exucted over a thousand times per second, even 1100 in some cases.

Comment: @dirkgently: Your "see this article" link no longer links to any article, but just the prof's home page.

Comment: @dirkgently, Can you please provide the link for " MS `cl` ..." statement ? And, even for the " GNU `libc` used to have ..." statement? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I can assure you, **the function `strcmp` is ABSOLUTELY NOT the bottleneck**.  Typically, strcmp is well optimized and can do 32 or 64 bit comparisons for strings longer than 4/8 bytes depending on architecture.  Both newlib and GNU libc do this.  But even if you were to look at each byte in both strings 20 times, it doesn't matter as much as the algo & data structure choices made here.

**The real bottle neck is the O(N) search algorithm**.  A single O(N log N) pass at the file could be used to at appropriate data structure (whether it's a normal BST, a trie, or just a simple sorted array) for doing O(log N) lookups.

Bear with me here--a lot of math follows. But I think this is a good opportunity to illustrate why choice of algorithm & data structure are sometimes FAR more important than method of string comparison.  Steve touches on this, but I wanted to explain it in a little more depth.

With N=1e6, log(1e6, 2) = 19.9, so round up to 20 comparisons on an ideal data structure.

Currently you're doing a a worst case search of O(N), or 1e6 operations.

So say you just build a red-black tree with O(log N) insertion time, and you insert N items, that's O(N log N) time to build the tree.  So that's 1e6 x 20 or 20e6 operations necessary to build your tree.

In your current approach, building the data structure is O(N), or 1e6 operations, but your worst case search time is O(N) as well.  So by the time you read the file and do just 20 search operations, you're up to a theoretical worst case of 21,000,000 operations.  By comparison,  your worst case with a red-black tree and 20 searches is 20,000,400 operations, or 999,600 operations BETTER than the O(N) search on an unsorted array.   So at 20 searches, you're at the first point where a more sophisticated data structure really pays off.  But look at what happens at 1000 searches:

Unsorted array = initialization + 1000 x search time = O(N) + 1000 * O(N) = 1,000,000 + 2,000,000,000 = 2,001,000,000 operations.

Red-black = initialization + 1000 x search time = O(N log N) + 1000 * O(log N) =  20,000,000 + 20,000 = 20,020,000 operations.

2,001,000,000 / 20,020,000 ~= 100x as many operations for the O(N) search.

At 1e6 searches, that's (1e6 + 1e6 * 1e6) / (20e6 + 1e6 * 20 ) = 25,000x as many operations.

Assume your computer can handle the 40e6 'operations' it takes to do the log N searches in 1 minute.  It would take 25,000 minutes, or 17 DAYS to do the same work with your current algorithm.  Or another way to look at is that the O(N) search algorithm can only handle 39 searches in the time the O(log N) algorithm can do 1,000,000.  And the more searches you do, the uglier it gets.

See responses from Steve and dirkgently for several better choices of data structures & algorithms.  My only additional caution would be that `qsort()` suggested by Steve *might* have a worst-case complexity of O(N*N), which is far, far, worse than the O(N log N) you get with a heapsort or various tree-like structures.

Answer (score 5):

[Optimization of Computer Programs in C](https://web.archive.org/web/20190409005610/http://leto.net/docs/C-optimization.php)

> You can save a little time by checking the first characters of the strings in question before doing the call. Obviously, if the first characters differ, there's no reason to call strcmp to check the rest. Because of the non-uniform distribution of letters in natural languages, the payoff is not 26:1 but more like 15:1 for uppercase data.

```
#define QUICKIE_STRCMP(a, b)  (*(a) != *(b) ? \  
  (int) ((unsigned char) *(a) - \
         (unsigned char) *(b)) : \
  strcmp((a), (b)))
```

If The dictionary of words you are using are well defined (meaning you don't mind return value form strcmp but the 0==equal), for example, a set of command line arguments that begins with same prefix, ex: tcp-accept, tcp-reject than you can rewrite the macro and do some pointer arithmetic to compare not the 1st one but the Nth char, in this case, the 4th char, ex:

```
   #define QUICKIE_STRCMP(a, b, offset) \
            (*(a+offset) != *(b+offset))\ ? -1 : strcmp((a), (b)))
```

Comment: I really doubt that the macro comparing the first characters yields better results for modern compilers and libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question correctly, you need to check if a string is along all the lines read so far. I would propose using a TRIE or even better a [Patricia tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_tree) from the file lines. This way instead of going all over all the lines you can check linearly if your string is present(and with a little more effort - where).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something 'cheap' like screening based on the first char. If the first chars don't match, the strings cannot be equal. If they match, then call strcmp to compare the entire string. You may wish to consider a better algorithm if that is appropriate for your situation; examples would be sorting the file/lines and doing a binary search, using a hash table, or similar string table techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You're already compiling with optimization, right?

If you have a Trie or hashtable data structure lying around the place, ready to use, then you should.

Failing that, a fairly easy change that will probably speed things up is to sort your array `line` once, before you start generating strings to search for. Then binary search for `buffer` in the sorted array. It's easy because the two functions you need are standard -- `qsort` and `bsearch`.

A binary search into a sorted array only needs to do about log<sub>2</sub>(filelines) string comparisons, instead of about filelines. So in your case that's 20-something string comparisons per call to `generate_string` instead of a few million. From the figures you've given, I think you can reasonably expect it to go 20-25 times faster, although I promise nothing.

Comment: The function `qsort()` could be a quicksort as the name implies, which has O(N*N) worst-case performance.  Unless I was certain how `qsort()` behaves on the target platform, I would go with the slower on average, but much faster on worst-case hepasort or smoothsort.

Comment: @Brian: If you prefer. As I said, the advantage of `qsort` is that it's standard. If I have to do the work myself then I'd probably rather write a hashtable than a heapsort, to be honest :-) Anyway, it's not entirely clear whether the start-up time matters at all, compared with the number of strings generated per second once we're up and running. If start-up time doesn't really matter, then `qsort` implemented as a bubble sort would be absolutely fine!

Comment: A proven sort algorithm is probably harder to screw up than a hashing function, and a bad hashing function puts you back at a worst case of O(N) search time.

Comment: @Brian: djbhash is good enough for me, but it's true that hashtables also have catastrophic worst-case performance. Some analysis is in order, whether the list of strings in `lines` might be maliciously constructed as a quicksort- and/or hash-killer. If you're worried about that sort of thing, then you have to decide whether to write your own algorithms, or just to pick a standard library whose `qsort` is resistant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a byte-wise comparator macro instead of `strcmp()` to achieve a very fast string comparison (of standard 8-bit `char`) if you know the string length beforehand. I benchmarked the byte-wise comparator macro against glibc's `strcmp()`, and the macro version significantly outperformed `strcmp()` implementation; it takes advantage of the CPU's [vector processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor).

Example:

```c
#define str3_cmp(x, y0, y1, y2, y3) x[0] == y0 && x[1] == y1 && x[2] == y2 && x[3] == y3
static inline bool str3_cmp_helper(const char *x, const char *y) {
    return str3_cmp(x, *y, *(y + 1), *(y + 2), *(y + 3));
}

const char *i = "hola"; // dynamically generated (eg: received over a network)

if (str3_cmp_helper(i, "hola")) {
     /* do something */ 
} else { 
    /* do something else */ 
}
```

However, writing such a macro is tiresome, so I have included a PHP script to generate the macro. This script takes two arguments, (1) the string length to be compared (this argument is [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) so write as many macros as you want), and (2) the output filename.

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
function generate_macro($num) : string {
        $returner = "#define str".$num."cmp_macro(ptr, ";
        for($x = 0; $x < $num; $x++){
                $returner .= "c".$x;
                if($x != $num-1){ $returner .= ", "; }
        }
        $returner .= ") ";
        for($x = 0; $x < $num; $x++){
                $returner .= "*(ptr+".$x.") == c".$x;
                if($x != $num-1){ $returner .= " && "; }
        }
        return $returner;
}
function generate_static_inline_fn(&$generated_macro, $num) : string {
        $generated_macro .= "static inline bool str".$num."cmp(const char* ptr, const char* cmp)".
                                "{\n\t\treturn str".$num."cmp_macro(ptr, ";
        for($x = 0; $x < $num; $x++){
                $generated_macro .= " *(cmp+".$x.")";
                if($x != $num-1){ $generated_macro .= ", "; }
        }
        $generated_macro .= ");\n}\n";
        return $generated_macro;
}

function handle_generation($argc, $argv) : void {
        $out_filename = $argv[$argc-1];
        $gen_macro = "";
        for($x = 0; $x < $argc-2; $x++){
                $macro = generate_macro($argv[$x+1])."\n";
                $gen_macro .= generate_static_inline_fn($macro, $argv[$x+1]);
        }
        file_put_contents($out_filename, $gen_macro);
}
handle_generation($argc, $argv);
?>
```

Script example: `$ ./gen_faststrcmp.php 3 5 fast_strcmp.h`.

This generates `fast_strcmp.h` with macros for comparing strings of length 3 and 5:

```c
#define str3cmp_macro(ptr, c0, c1, c2) *(ptr+0) == c0 && *(ptr+1) == c1 && *(ptr+2) == c2
static inline bool str3cmp(const char* ptr, const char* cmp){
                return str3cmp_macro(ptr,  *(cmp+0),  *(cmp+1),  *(cmp+2));
}
#define str5cmp_macro(ptr, c0, c1, c2, c3, c4) *(ptr+0) == c0 && *(ptr+1) == c1 && *(ptr+2) == c2 && *(ptr+3) == c3 && *(ptr+4) == c4
static inline bool str5cmp(const char* ptr, const char* cmp){
                return str5cmp_macro(ptr,  *(cmp+0),  *(cmp+1),  *(cmp+2),  *(cmp+3),  *(cmp+4));
}
```

You can use the macro like so:

```c
const char* compare_me = "Hello";
if(str5cmp(compare_me, "Hello")) { /* code goes here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there's a faster way than calling `strcmp` to do string comparisons, but you can perhaps *avoid* calling `strcmp` so much. Use a hash table to store your strings and then you can check whether the string in `buffer` is in the hash table. If the index of a hit is important when you "do something", the table can map strings to indexes.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to get by with a binary comparison in this case because your program does not actually *sort*, but compares for equality.

you can also improve comparison speeds here by determining the lengths in advance (provided of course they vary enough). when the length does not match here, `do something` will not happen.

of course, hashing here would be another consideration depending on how many times you read the hashed value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the length of the string.

If it's not too long, you can try to compare byte by byte:

```c
str[0] == str2[0] && str[1] == str2[1] && str[2] == str2[2]
```

Otherwise, use `memcmp()`, it compares chunks of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcmp` for regular strings. But if the string if really long you can use `memcmp`. It will compare chunks of memory.